# Generate a ppt with all images using php presentation

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppresentation

I am trying to generate a ppt using PHPPresentation-https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation which has all the slides with images. And the size of images can vary from 10-15mb or even more.. which is the requirement of project to have high quality image.

I have achieved it using PHPPresentation, but the problem is where the ppt size is getting too large, the server just gives a Internal server error-500 and exits the script on godaddy windows iis server.

So can anyone suggest how do i achieve this ? And not have errors for larger ppt size.

Comment: Sounds like you need to allow your script to use more memory.

Comment: i do have added memory_limit to the script.. still it dies with 500 error

Comment: The 500 error is what you'd see on the client side. What errors are you getting on the server? Check your error logs.

Comment: i dont get error logs as the project is deployed on  godaddy windows iis server. i have spoken with the support people also at godaddy.. but no use